# Reused GWT Widget becomes not visible

Tags: gwt, reusability

I have `Widget` with a `TabBar`.

```
<g:DockLayoutPanel unit="EM">
  <g:north size="2.5">
    <g:TabBar height="2.5em" ui:field="tabBar" />
  </g:north>
  <g:center>
    <g:SimpleLayoutPanel ui:field="contentWidget" />
  </g:center>
</g:DockLayoutPanel>
```

If user selects a tab, I set the widget for `contentWidget`.

```
@UiHandler("tabBar")
void onTabsSelection(final SelectionEvent<Integer> event) {
  // ...
}
```

This works perfectly!

Several tabs have ONE Widget in common, so I want to use a single instance of this widget (for sync).

```
<g:LayoutPanel>
  <!-- query -->
  <g:layer top="0" height="3em">
    <g:HorizontalPanel width="100%" height="3em" verticalAlignment="ALIGN_MIDDLE">
      <g:SimpleLayoutPanel ui:field="queryNode" />
      <g:cell horizontalAlignment="ALIGN_RIGHT">
        <my:StepPager ui:field="pager" />
      </g:cell>
    </g:HorizontalPanel>
  </g:layer>
  <!-- map -->
  <g:layer left="0" right="17em" top="3em" bottom="0">
    <g:SimpleLayoutPanel ui:field="mapNode" />
  </g:layer>
</g:LayoutPanel>
```

Of course a widget can only be attached to one parent. So I override the `onAttach` method for all the tab-wigets to read my query-widget.

```
@Override
protected void onAttach() {
  queryNode.setWidget(queryBar);
  super.onAttach();
}
```

The method will be invoked and the widget is in the DOM but it's not visible. I think the problem is that the cell of `SimpleLayoutPanel` `queryNode` size is 3x35 px.

Comment: It would be way easier to just make duplicates of the widget in question.  Have you already tried that, and identified it as a bottleneck?

Comment: Yes it's the current productive version. In one of Google GWT talks they say you should reuse widgets. That's why I want to do it. (And I don't need to maintain the events to sync every possible instance and change.